# Video flicker once upon change of source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have a video as 100% width & height, over that are interactive elements, when you click on the chapter it goes to white and then loads in a video very quickly.. when the video ends & you click on the video, it will go to the next video and again it goes to white and loads the video.

My issue is that it goes to a white screen for ~500ms, because I change the video source of the video-frame, the background-color of the body is white so I believe that's where the white comes from, changing the background color to blue or black changes the issue witht he white in their respective color, I was wondering if there is a solution for this?

I've suggested the following:
Loading screen for the ~500ms it goes to white.. this however doesn't look good.

First frame of the next video as background of the body, where I load the video over, so that it appears to be on the video but it's actually loading in the video.

The code as to how I change the video frame to the next video:

```
$("#klikimg").on('click', function(){

                switch(klik) {


                    case 100:
                        $("#wereldbol").attr("src", "aardeFrag/klik1.mp4");
                        klik = 90;
                    break;
    });
```

Comment: May sound too easy for an acceptable solution but does anything speak against setting the background to black or loading the 2nd video over the first one and removing the first when the 2nd started playing?

Comment: I will give it a try, and the background to black works fine it just doesn't look good at all, thank you give me a moment to implement it please

Comment: You may want to use z-index (CSS) to ensure the layer depth is correct.

Comment: Something like `$vc = $("#wereldbol").clone().src($newsrc).css({"z-index":"2"}); $("#wereldbol").addClass("old_content").css({"z-index":"1"}).parent().append($vc);` and when the 2nd video starts playing, you do `$(".old_content").remove();`

Comment: That's what I am currently using, it also appears that using two video's makes the browser quite a bit slower.. this would've to be done for 15 video's, do you see anyway to get my idea with images working? I've tried coding it exactly the same as the example seen above edit: ah I didn't see your new post thank you

Comment: Speaking of images... If you've got an image of the first video frame, you could set it as background image, wait for the browser to load it and then replace the video.

Comment: I do have images of the first frame, this is what I tried at first.. unfortunately it showed a white background for some reason

Comment: That basically means the image didn't load or didn't finish loading at the time you replace the video with the next one. You could use i.e. firebug or set up a blank site to check if the images load up at all. Maybe they are corrupt or in a format your browser can't display.

Comment: Sir, thank you, I have the answer now I'll post it down below, they're in png format so any browser should be able to display them, and if I do encounter a loading issue, I'll just set a timeout between the image starting to load and changing the video source

Comment: It works perfectly for one video, but still goes to black when I have multiple images & video's.. as for every new video I would need to load in a new images, which would still cause the black/white screen to occur

Comment: Try preloading the images in background at 1 x 1px with zero opacity or smth. If you've got 15 videos only, this shouldn't take too long and remove all loading delay issues.

Comment: I will try that, thank you give me a moment

Comment: Chris S. your solution worked, I will edit my post down below and credit you, thank you, sir I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Chris S. his suggestion of trying image frames again I did the following:

html:

```
    <video src="Wereldbol.mp4" onclick="this.play();" id='wereldbol' preload="auto" > </video>
```

Loaded the video in after the image, so that it wouldn't fall back on white or black for example.

CSS:

```
#tFrame{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
background-size:cover;
}
```

this is the css code I used, thank you, Chris S

note - this only works for one video source changing, as whenever it loads in a new frame it still goes to black if you don't have the image already present on the page

edit: For multiple video's: Load in every image at the beginning of your body tag, give them all the same class, and a width of 1px, height of 1 px and opacity of 0, then when you change your video source, change the width & height of the image you need to 100% and opacity to 1, on the next click, just before you change the image again change the image width & height to 1px and opacity to 0, this way it won't go to white or black -- Credit to: Chris S. for this solution, thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a hidden div on top of the video element, show this div before you set the src of the video and hide it again on video's `loadeddata` event:

```
case 100:
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
    $("#wereldbol").attr("src", "aardeFrag/klik1.mp4");
    klik = 90;
    break;
```

and on document ready:

```
$("#wereldbol").on("loadeddata", function() { $("#loadingDiv").hide(); } );
```

You can find the supported media events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: This would work but only for a website with one video, as I would be changing the frames aswell, which still causes the black/white screen to come up

Comment: @Gerwin What do you mean by "changing frames"?

Comment: I assumed that within the loadingDiv was an image of the first frame of the next video, is this not the case Sir? @artm

Comment: @Gerwin No, I meant `loadingDiv` to be something like `<div>Loading video, please wait.</div>`, which will cover the entire video. Or you can put a loading gif inside it.

Comment: ah alright, thank you for your further explanation, I have suggested that but they didn't think it would be suitable or look good, I will try to use the solution Chris S provided, but thank you for your time and effort

Comment: @Gerwin I suggest you give this a try and see for yourself, it may not be as bad as you think. You can use fadeOut or similar on the div for a smooth effect to show the video. It'll take a few minutes to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've similar problem and I've solved just creating differents video dom elements and append it in to the DOM. When a new video to be played appears just remove from the dom the older and add the new dom video element to the DOM. Here is an example of my code:`

```
function playVideo(aviso){
  let newVideo = document.createElement('video');
  newVideo.style.cursor = 'none !important';
  newVideo.style.width = pantalla.width;
  newVideo.style.height = pantalla.height;
  newVideo.muted = true;
  newVideo.src = aviso.url;
  newVideo.style.objectFit  = 'contain';
  const sourceElem = document.createElement('source');
  sourceElem.src = '';
  const pElem = document.createElement('P');
  pElem.innerHTML = 'No soporta video';
  newVideo.appendChild(sourceElem);
  newVideo.appendChild(pElem);
  newVideo.oncanplay = function() {
    // video.style.visibility = 'visible';
    removeCurrents();
    document.body.appendChild(newVideo);
    newVideo.play();
    currentVideo = newVideo;
  };
```

`